# Unable to add HTTP headers with Android Webview

Tags: android, android-webview

As far as I can tell, I'm doing this correctly. However, the headers simply are not added. Any help is appreciated. Here's the code:

```
Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
headers.put("key", "value");
webView.loadUrl("https://www.*website*.com/index.php", headers);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong to assume the header key could be arbitrary. Prefixed with an 'X-', everything works.